# Predict API in Django

Tags: python, django, tensorflow-serving

I have a Tensorflow model which I saved using TensorFlow serving. I now wish to retrieve results from the database and make predictions using API in DJANGO.

The model is callable from UBUNTU using curl and gives correct predictions:

I have tried to call the API from DJANGO. For this my views.py file looks like this:

```
normed_data = normed_data.to_dict()  # normed_data is a dataframe with header values as well  
   
   response = normed_data.get('http://localhost:8501/v1/models/model:predict')        
   context = {
      'df2' : response
   }

   return render(request, "view.html", context)
```

But the result is

None

Any help in pointing my errors out would be really wonderful. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
API_ENDPOINT = 'http://localhost:8501/v1/models/model:predict'
response = requests.post(url = API_ENDPOINT, data = json.dumps(normed_data))
```